# Adding event listener to several comboboxes

Tags: vba, excel, combobox, userform

I'm basically trying to display different sets of textboxes on a userform depending on the value taken by a combobox. I have created a class module called CControlEvents in which I describe the events that should occur when I change the value of the combobox :

```
Private WithEvents mclsCbx As MSForms.ComboBox

Private WithEvents UnitmclsTbx As MSForms.TextBox
Private WithEvents UnitmclsTbxLabel As MSForms.Label

Private WithEvents SpecMinMoymclsTbxLabel As MSForms.Label
Private WithEvents SpecMaxMoymclsTbxLabel As MSForms.Label

Private WithEvents SpecMinIndmclsTbxLabel As MSForms.Label
Private WithEvents SpecMaxIndmclsTbxLabel As MSForms.Label

Private WithEvents SpecMinMoymclsTbx As MSForms.TextBox
Private WithEvents SpecMaxMoymclsTbx As MSForms.TextBox
Private WithEvents SpecMinIndmclsTbx As MSForms.TextBox
Private WithEvents SpecMaxIndmclsTbx As MSForms.TextBox

Private WithEvents ListmclsTbxLabel As MSForms.Label
Private WithEvents ListmclsTbx As MSForms.TextBox

Private mMyProperty As Integer

Public Property Set Cbx(ByVal clsCbx As MSForms.ComboBox): Set mclsCbx = clsCbx: End Property
Public Property Get Cbx() As MSForms.ComboBox: Set Cbx = mclsCbx: End Property

'Property pour les textbox et labels
'TextBox d'unité
Public Property Set UnitTbx(ByVal clsTbx As MSForms.TextBox): Set UnitmclsTbx = clsTbx: End Property
Public Property Get UnitTbx() As MSForms.TextBox: Set UnitTbx = UnitmclsTbx: End Property
'Label d'unité
Public Property Set UnitTbxLabel(ByVal clsTbx As MSForms.Label): Set UnitmclsTbxLabel = clsTbx: End Property
Public Property Get UnitTbxLabel() As MSForms.Label: Set UnitTbxLabel = UnitmclsTbxLabel: End Property

'TextBox de spécification minimum moyenne
Public Property Set SpecMinMoyTbx(ByVal clsTbx As MSForms.TextBox): Set SpecMinMoymclsTbx = clsTbx: End Property
Public Property Get SpecMinMoyTbx() As MSForms.TextBox: Set SpecMinMoyTbx = SpecMinMoymclsTbx: End Property
'Label de spécification minimum moyenne
Public Property Set SpecMinMoyTbxLabel(ByVal clsTbx As MSForms.Label): Set SpecMinMoymclsTbxLabel = clsTbx: End Property
Public Property Get SpecMinMoyTbxLabel() As MSForms.Label: Set SpecMinMoyTbxLabel = SpecMinMoymclsTbxLabel: End Property
'Label de spécification maximum moyenne
Public Property Set SpecMaxMoyTbxLabel(ByVal clsTbx As MSForms.Label): Set SpecMaxMoymclsTbxLabel = clsTbx: End Property
Public Property Get SpecMaxMoyTbxLabel() As MSForms.Label: Set SpecMaxMoyTbxLabel = SpecMaxMoymclsTbxLabel: End Property
'TextBox de spécification max moy
Public Property Set SpecMaxMoyTbx(ByVal clsTbx As MSForms.TextBox): Set SpecMaxMoymclsTbx = clsTbx: End Property
Public Property Get SpecMaxMoyTbx() As MSForms.TextBox: Set SpecMaxMoyTbx = SpecMaxMoymclsTbx: End Property

'TextBox de spécification minimum individuelle
Public Property Set SpecMinIndTbx(ByVal clsTbx As MSForms.TextBox): Set SpecMinIndmclsTbx = clsTbx: End Property
Public Property Get SpecMinIndTbx() As MSForms.TextBox: Set SpecMinIndTbx = SpecMinIndmclsTbx: End Property
'Label de spécification minimum individuelle
Public Property Set SpecMinIndTbxLabel(ByVal clsTbx As MSForms.Label): Set SpecMinIndmclsTbxLabel = clsTbx: End Property
Public Property Get SpecMinIndTbxLabel() As MSForms.Label: Set SpecMinIndTbxLabel = SpecMinIndmclsTbxLabel: End Property
'Label de spécification maximum individuelle
Public Property Set SpecMaxIndTbxLabel(ByVal clsTbx As MSForms.Label): Set SpecMaxIndmclsTbxLabel = clsTbx: End Property
Public Property Get SpecMaxIndTbxLabel() As MSForms.Label: Set SpecMaxIndTbxLabel = SpecMaxIndmclsTbxLabel: End Property
'TextBox de spécification max individuelle
Public Property Set SpecMaxIndTbx(ByVal clsTbx As MSForms.TextBox): Set SpecMaxIndmclsTbx = clsTbx: End Property
Public Property Get SpecMaxIndTbx() As MSForms.TextBox: Set SpecMaxIndTbx = SpecMaxIndmclsTbx: End Property

'TextBox de liste déroulante
Public Property Set ListTbx(ByVal clsTbx As MSForms.TextBox): Set ListmclsTbx = clsTbx: End Property
Public Property Get ListTbx() As MSForms.TextBox: Set ListTbx = ListmclsTbx: End Property
'Label de liste déroulante
Public Property Set ListTbxLabel(ByVal clsTbx As MSForms.Label): Set ListmclsTbxLabel = clsTbx: End Property
Public Property Get ListTbxLabel() As MSForms.Label: Set ListTbxLabel = ListmclsTbxLabel: End Property

Public Property Get MyProperty() As Integer
MyProperty = mMyProperty
End Property

Public Property Let Transition(Value As Integer)
mMyProperty = Value
End Property


Private Sub mclsCbx_Change()

If (Me.Cbx.Text = "NUM") Then

    UnitTbx.Visible = True
    UnitmclsTbxLabel.Visible = True
    SpecMinMoymclsTbxLabel.Visible = True
    SpecMinMoymclsTbx.Visible = True
    SpecMaxMoymclsTbx.Visible = True
    SpecMaxMoymclsTbxLabel.Visible = True

    SpecMinIndmclsTbxLabel.Visible = True
    SpecMinIndmclsTbx.Visible = True
    SpecMaxIndmclsTbx.Visible = True
    SpecMaxIndmclsTbxLabel.Visible = True

    ListmclsTbx.Visible = False
    ListmclsTbxLabel.Visible = False

Else
    If (Me.Cbx.Text = "LIST") Then
        UnitTbx.Visible = False
        UnitmclsTbxLabel.Visible = False
        SpecMinMoymclsTbxLabel.Visible = False
        SpecMinMoymclsTbx.Visible = False
        SpecMaxMoymclsTbx.Visible = False
        SpecMaxMoymclsTbxLabel.Visible = False

        SpecMinIndmclsTbxLabel.Visible = False
        SpecMinIndmclsTbx.Visible = False
        SpecMaxIndmclsTbx.Visible = False
        SpecMaxIndmclsTbxLabel.Visible = False

        ListmclsTbx.Visible = True
        ListmclsTbxLabel.Visible = True

    End If
End If

End Sub
```

In the userform's code, I dynamically add such comboboxes :

```
Set gclsControlEvents = New CControlEvents
    'On attribue la comboBox à une propriété de la classe créée
    Set gclsControlEvents.Cbx = oleCbx
    'On attribue une zone de texte à une propriété de la classe créée
    Set gclsControlEvents.UnitTbx = numUnitTextBox
    'Label unité
    Set gclsControlEvents.UnitTbxLabel = UnitmclsTbxLabel
    'Label spéc moy min
    Set gclsControlEvents.SpecMinMoyTbxLabel = SpecMinMoyTbxLabel
    'Zone de texte spéc moy min
    Set gclsControlEvents.SpecMinMoyTbx = SpecMinMoymclsTbx
    'Label spéc max min
    Set gclsControlEvents.SpecMaxMoyTbxLabel = SpecMaxMoyTbxLabel
    'Zone de texte spéc moy max
    Set gclsControlEvents.SpecMaxMoyTbx = SpecMaxMoymclsTbx
```

So, I basically add the controls in the userform code and assign them to properties of the class, then I can simply hide/show as appropriate. The problem is that when I try to add several comboboxes based on this principle, using a for loop, it works only for the last comboboxe.

**EDIT** : The for loop

```
    For i = 1 To NewSheetModelColumnsCount
     Set Lbl = Frame1.Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1", "lbl1")
     Set txtB1 = Frame1.Add("Forms.TextBox.1")

'Create the combobox
Set oleCbx = Frame1.Add("Forms.ComboBox.1") 'Bug at this line

With oleCbx
    .name = "list" & i
    .Height = 15
    .Width = 100
    .Left = 70
    .Top = 10 * i * 3
    .AddItem "NUM"
    .AddItem "LIST"
End With

        With txtB1
            .name = "chkDemo" & i
            .Height = 15
            .Width = 100
            .Left = 230
            .Top = 10 * i * 3
        End With

        Lbl.Caption = "Colonne n°" + CStr(i)
        Lbl.Top = txtB1.Top
        Lbl.Left = 10

        Set lbl2 = Frame1.Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1", "lbl2")

        lbl2.Caption = "Intitulé : "
        lbl2.Top = txtB1.Top
        lbl2.Left = 180
        lbl2.Visible = True
        lbl2.Width = 50

Set UnitmclsTbxLabel = UserForm1.Frame1.Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1", "UnitmclsTbxLabel")
Set ListmclsTbxLabel = UserForm1.Frame1.Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1", "ListmclsTbxLabel")

Set SpecMinMoyTbxLabel = UserForm1.Frame1.Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1", "SpecMinMoyTbxLabel")
Set SpecMaxMoyTbxLabel = UserForm1.Frame1.Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1", "SpecMinMoyTbxLabel")

Set SpecMinIndTbxLabel = UserForm1.Frame1.Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1", "SpecMinIndTbxLabel")
Set SpecMaxIndTbxLabel = UserForm1.Frame1.Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1", "SpecMinIndTbxLabel")

UnitmclsTbxLabel.Caption = "Unité : "
UnitmclsTbxLabel.Left = 360

UnitmclsTbxLabel.Visible = False

Set numUnitTextBox = UserForm1.Frame1.Add("Forms.TextBox.1")
Set SpecMinMoymclsTbx = UserForm1.Frame1.Add("Forms.TextBox.1")
Set SpecMaxMoymclsTbx = UserForm1.Frame1.Add("Forms.TextBox.1")

Set SpecMinIndmclsTbx = UserForm1.Frame1.Add("Forms.TextBox.1")
Set SpecMaxIndmclsTbx = UserForm1.Frame1.Add("Forms.TextBox.1")

Set ListTextBox = UserForm1.Frame1.Add("Forms.TextBox.1")

SpecMinMoymclsTbx.Width = 50
SpecMaxMoymclsTbx.Width = 50
SpecMinIndmclsTbx.Width = 50
SpecMaxIndmclsTbx.Width = 50

With numUnitTextBox
        .name = "Unit" & i
        .Height = 15
        .Width = 50
        .Left = 360 + UnitmclsTbxLabel.Width - 40
        .Top = 10 * i * 3
        .Value = "Unit"
End With

ListTextBox.Top = numUnitTextBox.Top
ListTextBox.Left = numUnitTextBox.Left + numUnitTextBox.Width - 40
ListTextBox.Visible = False
ListTextBox.Width = 200

ListmclsTbxLabel.Caption = "Options : "
ListmclsTbxLabel.Visible = False
ListmclsTbxLabel.Top = numUnitTextBox.Top
ListmclsTbxLabel.Left = 360

UnitmclsTbxLabel.Top = numUnitTextBox.Top
SpecMinMoyTbxLabel.Top = numUnitTextBox.Top
SpecMinMoyTbxLabel.Left = numUnitTextBox.Left + numUnitTextBox.Width + 5
SpecMinMoyTbxLabel.Caption = "Spéc min Moy : "
SpecMinMoyTbxLabel.Visible = False
SpecMinMoymclsTbx.Top = numUnitTextBox.Top
SpecMinMoymclsTbx.Visible = False
SpecMinMoymclsTbx.Left = SpecMinMoyTbxLabel.Left + SpecMinMoyTbxLabel.Width - 15
SpecMaxMoyTbxLabel.Visible = False
SpecMaxMoyTbxLabel.Caption = "Spéc max moy : "
SpecMaxMoyTbxLabel.Left = SpecMinMoymclsTbx.Left + SpecMinMoymclsTbx.Width
SpecMaxMoyTbxLabel.Top = numUnitTextBox.Top
SpecMaxMoymclsTbx.Visible = False
SpecMaxMoymclsTbx.Top = numUnitTextBox.Top
SpecMaxMoymclsTbx.Left = SpecMaxMoyTbxLabel.Left + SpecMaxMoyTbxLabel.Width

SpecMinIndTbxLabel.Top = numUnitTextBox.Top
SpecMinIndTbxLabel.Left = SpecMaxMoymclsTbx.Left + SpecMaxMoymclsTbx.Width + 5
SpecMinIndTbxLabel.Caption = "Spéc min Ind : "
SpecMinIndTbxLabel.Visible = False
SpecMinIndmclsTbx.Top = numUnitTextBox.Top
SpecMinIndmclsTbx.Visible = False
SpecMinIndmclsTbx.Left = SpecMinIndTbxLabel.Left + SpecMinIndTbxLabel.Width - 15
SpecMaxIndTbxLabel.Visible = False
SpecMaxIndTbxLabel.Caption = "Spéc max moy : "
SpecMaxIndTbxLabel.Left = SpecMinIndmclsTbx.Left + SpecMinIndmclsTbx.Width
SpecMaxIndTbxLabel.Top = numUnitTextBox.Top
SpecMaxIndmclsTbx.Visible = False
SpecMaxIndmclsTbx.Top = numUnitTextBox.Top
SpecMaxIndmclsTbx.Left = SpecMaxIndTbxLabel.Left + SpecMaxIndTbxLabel.Width

numUnitTextBox.Visible = False

Set gclsControlEvents = New CControlEvents
'On attribue la comboBox à une propriété de la classe créée
Set gclsControlEvents.Cbx = oleCbx
'On attribue une zone de texte à une propriété de la classe créée
Set gclsControlEvents.UnitTbx = numUnitTextBox
'Label unité
Set gclsControlEvents.UnitTbxLabel = UnitmclsTbxLabel
'Label spéc moy min
Set gclsControlEvents.SpecMinMoyTbxLabel = SpecMinMoyTbxLabel
'Zone de texte spéc moy min
Set gclsControlEvents.SpecMinMoyTbx = SpecMinMoymclsTbx
'Label spéc max min
Set gclsControlEvents.SpecMaxMoyTbxLabel = SpecMaxMoyTbxLabel
'Zone de texte spéc moy max
Set gclsControlEvents.SpecMaxMoyTbx = SpecMaxMoymclsTbx

'Label spéc moy min
Set gclsControlEvents.SpecMinIndTbxLabel = SpecMinIndTbxLabel
'Zone de texte spéc moy min
Set gclsControlEvents.SpecMinIndTbx = SpecMinIndmclsTbx
'Label spéc max min
Set gclsControlEvents.SpecMaxIndTbxLabel = SpecMaxIndTbxLabel
'Zone de texte spéc moy max
Set gclsControlEvents.SpecMaxIndTbx = SpecMaxIndmclsTbx
'Zone de texte des options de la liste déroulante
Set gclsControlEvents.ListTbx = ListTextBox
'Label Options liste déroulante
Set gclsControlEvents.ListTbxLabel = ListmclsTbxLabel

Let gclsControlEvents.Transition = i

    Next i
```

**EDIT :**
I tried to solve the problem by creating a variant array of as many instances of the class CControlEvents as I need comboboxes then using the element of this array at index i-1 at each iteration, but it didn't work, here is the code :

```
If (NewSheetModelColumnsCount > 0) Then

       For i = 1 To 6
           Controls("headerTextBox" + CStr(i)).Visible = True
           Controls("CheckBox" + CStr(i)).Visible = True
       Next i

       For i = 11 To 16
           Controls("label" + CStr(i)).Visible = True
       Next i

       Me.indicationLabel.Visible = False

      'Name of the frame
        With Me.Frame1
            'This will create a vertical scrollbar
            .ScrollBars = fmScrollBarsVertical

            'Change the values of 2 as Per your requirements
            .ScrollHeight = 30 * NewSheetModelColumnsCount + 50
            .ScrollWidth = 30 * 50 + 50
            '
        End With

        'Tentative
        Dim classList As Variant
        ReDim classList(0 To NewSheetModelColumnsCount - 1)

        For i = 0 To NewSheetModelColumnsCount - 1
           Set classList(i) = New CControlEvents
        Next i

    For i = 1 To NewSheetModelColumnsCount
     Set Lbl = Frame1.Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1", "lbl1")
     Set txtB1 = Frame1.Add("Forms.TextBox.1")
   '  Set ListBoxB1 = Frame1.Controls.Add("Forms.ComboBox.1")

    '    With ListBoxB1
    '        .Name = "list" & i
    '        .Height = 15
    '        .Width = 100
    '        .Left = 70
    '        .Top = 10 * i * 3
    '        .AddItem "NUM"
    '        .AddItem "LIST"
    '    End With

'Create the combobox
Set oleCbx = Frame1.Add("Forms.ComboBox.1") 'Bug at this line

With oleCbx
    .name = "list" & i
    .Height = 15
    .Width = 100
    .Left = 70
    .Top = 10 * i * 3
    .AddItem "NUM"
    .AddItem "LIST"
End With

        With txtB1
            .name = "chkDemo" & i
            .Height = 15
            .Width = 100
            .Left = 230
            .Top = 10 * i * 3
        End With

        Lbl.Caption = "Colonne n°" + CStr(i)
        Lbl.Top = txtB1.Top
        Lbl.Left = 10

        Set lbl2 = Frame1.Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1", "lbl2")
        'Set txtB2 = Frame1.Add("Forms.TextBox.1")

       ' With txtB2
       '    .name = "unitTextBox" & i
       '    .Height = 15
       '    .Width = 100
       '    .Left = 240
       '    .Top = 10 * i * 3
       '    .Value = "txtB2"
       ' End With

        lbl2.Caption = "Intitulé : "
        lbl2.Top = txtB1.Top
        lbl2.Left = 180
        lbl2.Visible = True
        lbl2.Width = 50

Set UnitmclsTbxLabel = UserForm1.Frame1.Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1", "UnitmclsTbxLabel")
Set ListmclsTbxLabel = UserForm1.Frame1.Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1", "ListmclsTbxLabel")

Set SpecMinMoyTbxLabel = UserForm1.Frame1.Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1", "SpecMinMoyTbxLabel")
Set SpecMaxMoyTbxLabel = UserForm1.Frame1.Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1", "SpecMinMoyTbxLabel")

Set SpecMinIndTbxLabel = UserForm1.Frame1.Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1", "SpecMinIndTbxLabel")
Set SpecMaxIndTbxLabel = UserForm1.Frame1.Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1", "SpecMinIndTbxLabel")

UnitmclsTbxLabel.Caption = "Unité : "
UnitmclsTbxLabel.Left = 360

UnitmclsTbxLabel.Visible = False

Set numUnitTextBox = UserForm1.Frame1.Add("Forms.TextBox.1")
Set SpecMinMoymclsTbx = UserForm1.Frame1.Add("Forms.TextBox.1")
Set SpecMaxMoymclsTbx = UserForm1.Frame1.Add("Forms.TextBox.1")

Set SpecMinIndmclsTbx = UserForm1.Frame1.Add("Forms.TextBox.1")
Set SpecMaxIndmclsTbx = UserForm1.Frame1.Add("Forms.TextBox.1")

Set ListTextBox = UserForm1.Frame1.Add("Forms.TextBox.1")

SpecMinMoymclsTbx.Width = 50
SpecMaxMoymclsTbx.Width = 50
SpecMinIndmclsTbx.Width = 50
SpecMaxIndmclsTbx.Width = 50

With numUnitTextBox
        .name = "Unit" & i
        .Height = 15
        .Width = 50
        .Left = 360 + UnitmclsTbxLabel.Width - 40
        .Top = 10 * i * 3
        .Value = "Unit"
End With

ListTextBox.Top = numUnitTextBox.Top
ListTextBox.Left = numUnitTextBox.Left + numUnitTextBox.Width - 40
ListTextBox.Visible = False
ListTextBox.Width = 200

ListmclsTbxLabel.Caption = "Options : "
ListmclsTbxLabel.Visible = False
ListmclsTbxLabel.Top = numUnitTextBox.Top
ListmclsTbxLabel.Left = 360

UnitmclsTbxLabel.Top = numUnitTextBox.Top
SpecMinMoyTbxLabel.Top = numUnitTextBox.Top
SpecMinMoyTbxLabel.Left = numUnitTextBox.Left + numUnitTextBox.Width + 5
SpecMinMoyTbxLabel.Caption = "Spéc min Moy : "
SpecMinMoyTbxLabel.Visible = False
SpecMinMoymclsTbx.Top = numUnitTextBox.Top
SpecMinMoymclsTbx.Visible = False
SpecMinMoymclsTbx.Left = SpecMinMoyTbxLabel.Left + SpecMinMoyTbxLabel.Width - 15
SpecMaxMoyTbxLabel.Visible = False
SpecMaxMoyTbxLabel.Caption = "Spéc max moy : "
SpecMaxMoyTbxLabel.Left = SpecMinMoymclsTbx.Left + SpecMinMoymclsTbx.Width
SpecMaxMoyTbxLabel.Top = numUnitTextBox.Top
SpecMaxMoymclsTbx.Visible = False
SpecMaxMoymclsTbx.Top = numUnitTextBox.Top
SpecMaxMoymclsTbx.Left = SpecMaxMoyTbxLabel.Left + SpecMaxMoyTbxLabel.Width

SpecMinIndTbxLabel.Top = numUnitTextBox.Top
SpecMinIndTbxLabel.Left = SpecMaxMoymclsTbx.Left + SpecMaxMoymclsTbx.Width + 5
SpecMinIndTbxLabel.Caption = "Spéc min Ind : "
SpecMinIndTbxLabel.Visible = False
SpecMinIndmclsTbx.Top = numUnitTextBox.Top
SpecMinIndmclsTbx.Visible = False
SpecMinIndmclsTbx.Left = SpecMinIndTbxLabel.Left + SpecMinIndTbxLabel.Width - 15
SpecMaxIndTbxLabel.Visible = False
SpecMaxIndTbxLabel.Caption = "Spéc max moy : "
SpecMaxIndTbxLabel.Left = SpecMinIndmclsTbx.Left + SpecMinIndmclsTbx.Width
SpecMaxIndTbxLabel.Top = numUnitTextBox.Top
SpecMaxIndmclsTbx.Visible = False
SpecMaxIndmclsTbx.Top = numUnitTextBox.Top
SpecMaxIndmclsTbx.Left = SpecMaxIndTbxLabel.Left + SpecMaxIndTbxLabel.Width

numUnitTextBox.Visible = False

'Set gclsControlEvents = New CControlEvents
'On attribue la comboBox à une propriété de la classe créée
Set classList(i - 1).Cbx = oleCbx
'On attribue une zone de texte à une propriété de la classe créée
Set classList(i - 1).UnitTbx = numUnitTextBox
'Label unité
Set classList(i - 1).UnitTbxLabel = UnitmclsTbxLabel
'Label spéc moy min
Set classList(i - 1).SpecMinMoyTbxLabel = SpecMinMoyTbxLabel
'Zone de texte spéc moy min
Set classList(i - 1).SpecMinMoyTbx = SpecMinMoymclsTbx
'Label spéc max min
Set classList(i - 1).SpecMaxMoyTbxLabel = SpecMaxMoyTbxLabel
'Zone de texte spéc moy max
Set classList(i - 1).SpecMaxMoyTbx = SpecMaxMoymclsTbx

'Label spéc moy min
Set classList(i - 1).SpecMinIndTbxLabel = SpecMinIndTbxLabel
'Zone de texte spéc moy min
Set classList(i - 1).SpecMinIndTbx = SpecMinIndmclsTbx
'Label spéc max min
Set classList(i - 1).SpecMaxIndTbxLabel = SpecMaxIndTbxLabel
'Zone de texte spéc moy max
Set classList(i - 1).SpecMaxIndTbx = SpecMaxIndmclsTbx
'Zone de texte des options de la liste déroulante
Set classList(i - 1).ListTbx = ListTextBox
'Label Options liste déroulante
Set classList(i - 1).ListTbxLabel = ListmclsTbxLabel

Let classList(i - 1).Transition = i

       ' Set Lbl3 = Frame1.Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1", "lbl3")
       ' Set txtB3 = Frame1.Add("Forms.TextBox.1")

    '    With txtB3
     '        .Name = "specMin" & i
     '        .Height = 15
     '        .Width = 200
     '        .Left = 410
     '        .Top = 10 * i * 3
     '  End With

      ' Lbl3.Caption = "Eléments : "
      ' Lbl3.Top = txtB3.Top
      ' Lbl3.Left = 360

    Next i
 '
    'On modifie la visibilité des éléments pour ne permettre que la saisie du modèle courant
    Me.RedefineModelParamButton.Visible = True
    '
    Me.Label1.Visible = False
    Me.Label2.Visible = False
    Me.Label3.Visible = False
    Me.Label21.Visible = False

    Me.NewSheetModelLabelTextBox.Visible = False
    Me.NewSheetModelColumnsNumberTextBox.Visible = False
    Me.SheetCategoryComboBox.Visible = False
    Me.EnterNewSheetModelColumnsCountValidateButton.Visible = False
    Me.EnterNewSheetModelColumnsCountCancelButton.Visible = False
    Me.fcmIndexComboBox1.Visible = False
    Me.fcmIndexComboBox2.Visible = False

End If
```

Comment: Please show us the for loop

Comment: I added it to the post @TobyAllen

Comment: looks to me like your using the same combobox on each iteration?  How do you use i to choose another combobox?

Comment: Actually the name of OleCbx depends of i in the "with" block but I guess it's not the proper way to do it, how can I solve this problem ?

Comment: I tried to solve the problem by creating a variant array of as many instances of the class CControlEvents as I need comboboxes then using the element of this array at index i-1 at each iteration, but it didn't work @TobyAllen

Comment: Try getting it to work with a much simpler setup.  Maybe 3 comboboxes on a form and write code to allow you to select differnt ones.  create strings to allow you to select differnt controls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `User-Form` declare a `VBA-Collection` and store the instances of your class which wraps `Combo-Boxes` in this collection. In your class declare a `Combo-Box` variable `WithEvents` so you can handle events of the `Combo-Box`. HTH.

> User Form

```
Private m_combos As New Collection

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Set m_combos = New Collection

    Dim i
    Dim newCombo As CControlEvents

    For i = 0 To 2
        Set newCombo = New CControlEvents

        With newCombo
            Set .Combo = Me.Frame1.Add("Forms.ComboBox.1")
            .Combo.Top = 20 * i
            .Combo.AddItem "A"
            .Combo.AddItem "B"
            .Combo.AddItem "C"
        End With

        m_combos.Add newCombo
    Next
End Sub
```

> CControlEvents

```
Private WithEvents m_combo As MSForms.ComboBox

Private Sub m_combo_Change()
    MsgBox "Change: " & Me.Combo.Name
End Sub

Public Property Get Combo() As MSForms.ComboBox
    Set Combo = m_combo
End Property

Public Property Set Combo(ByVal newCombo As MSForms.ComboBox)
    Set m_combo = newCombo
End Property
```

[image]