# Create a chart with own events

Tags: vba, excel

I have written a script which can add new charts with the `Charts.Add` function.

Now every new charts should have the same `Chart_MouseUp` Event. But as the chart only get created when the user needs it, I have no place to write the event code.

I need something like `Charts.Add*-with-default-mouseUp-Event*`

Comment: You could use a template chart, and copy that each time.

Comment: Couldn't it be simular to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31896707/adding-event-listener-to-several-comboboxes/31939689#31939689)?

Answer (score 0):

You can add this code behind your chart:

```
ChartObjects("Chart 1").OnAction = "yourMacro"
```

IMO this is as far as you can get with "events" and charts.